# Oracle select distinct with join and multiple columns

Tags: oracle, join, unique, distinct

Unfortunately this database has a ton of duplicate email addresses in it. I need to do a query and return only unique emails, doesn't really matter which one.

The query I have looks like this, can't really figure out what to add to not get duplicate emails returned. Can anyone think of anything?

```
select c.cid, c.email, c.uuid, e.code
from c
    inner join e on e.cid = c.cid
where regexp_like(c.email, '\.net$', 'i');
```

-- Adding some additional info on request

The above query returns the following results, where you can see there are duplicates. I'm interested in only returning one row per unique email address.

```
3478|cust1@cust1.net|ouskns;dhf|1
3488|cust2@cust2.net|jlsudo;uff|0
3598|cust3@cust3.net|dl;udjffff|1
3798|cust1@cust1.net|osuosdujff|1
3888|cust1@cust1.net|odsos7jfff|1
```

-- Solution, thanks Mathguy

```
select cid, email, uuid, code
from
  (select c.cid, c.email, c.uuid, e.code, row_number() over (partition by
    c.email order by null) as rn
   from c
    inner join e on e.cid = c.cid
   where regexp_like(c.email, '\.net$', 'i')
  )
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result

Comment: Please post what you expect; you need one row for address, but what about the other fields? random? max? min ?

Comment: Err... I see the example; so you don't care what ANY of the other values are? So you will pick one (random) row out of the five you show?

Comment: Yes, any random is fine... just don't want multiple rows returned with the same email address.

Comment: I still assumed that you want to return one of the rows (so the cid and uuid and code are matched) - so just selecting the email and max(cid) and max(uuid) wouldn't work, because max(cid) and max(uuid) may be on different rows for a given email. The solution I offered picks an entire row (with matched cid, uuid and code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works as is and the only problem is the duplicates, you can change `c.email` to `MAX(c.email) as email` in the `select` clause, and add a group by clause to group by the other columns included in `select`.

**EDIT**:  *(actually I should delete the original answer since the OP clarified his question was quite different from what he seemed to ask originally - but that would also delete the comments... so editing instead)*

If your query produces the desired results, but now you must pick just one random row per email address, you can try this:

```
select cid, email, uuid, code
from
   (  -- ....   copy your select query here
      --        ADD one column to the select line like so:
      --        select c.cid, c.uuid, c.email, e.code, 
      --                     row_number() over (partition by c.email order by null) as rn
      -- ....
   )
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: select c.cid, max(c.email), c.uuid, e.code from c inner join e on e.cid = c.cid where regexp_like(c.email, '\.net$', 'i') group by c.uuid, e.code;

Comment: @Bryan - that is not what I suggested. Two differences: I added the alias "as email" after the max(...) (otherwise your column name will be maxemail - is that what you want?) And you must include ALL THREE of the other columns in group by; you are missing c.cid and you will get an error.

Comment: Ok sorry, I missed the `as email`. I added that, and added the `c.id` and still get the duplicates returned.

Comment: I don't understand... if you group by c.cid (you wrote c.id, did you mean c.cid?), c.uuid and e.code, and return these three columns plus the max(c.email), then you should only get one row per c.cid, c.uuid, e.code. Is that REALLY your query or is it part of a larger one, and you are not showing us everything?

Comment: Or are you getting the same c.cid, DIFFERENT c.uuid, and different email (but since it's the same c.cid, you wanted the same email to be returned)? That is a different question from what you asked.

Comment: Its confusing to say at least... @brian the query of mathguy should indeed return what you asked. There's still something unclear: if you want all colums, what is your criteria to remove the duplicates email rows? Do you want to keep the first or last subscribed customer, or just random or something else?

Comment: Yes, I get one row per `c.id`. Please see the data output example, there are unique rows in the database that contain the same email address.

Comment: @ThomasG - Yeah, I think I got it - I posted a solution to the restated problem.

Comment: @Bryan: One row for id, but WHAT row? which values do you expect in this row? random? the row with the minimum id? with the max id? a row with mixed values from different rows ? ...mathguy is suggesting a random row, is it ok for you? please edit your question with this information

Comment: Thanks that worked mathguy, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Happy it worked. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using `DISTINCT` :

```
select DISTINCT c.email
from c
    inner join e on e.cid = c.cid
where regexp_like(c.email, '\.net$', 'i');
```

Or using `GROUP BY` (and you get the number of dups in the `cnt` column)

```
select c.email, count(*) as cnt
from c
    inner join e on e.cid = c.cid
where regexp_like(c.email, '\.net$', 'i')
GROUP BY c.email;
```

Comment: @mathguy you or I will provide what he wants. He never stated that he needs additional columns in the original SELECT clause, just all DISTINCT emails.  Your MAX will return the distinct emails indeed, but the other columns will be unmeaningfull so at the end the result is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, but yea... like mathguy said doesn't answer the question. I need more than just the email field.

Comment: Like I said, it's unfortunate but the database does have duplicates (not my doing). They are unique rows of data, as in customers were allowed to register multiple times with the same email address.

Comment: @Bryan - you confused readers by saying "duplicates". Duplicates means same email address everywhere; what you really have is multiple emails for the same cid, and THAT is your problem. If you just had duplicates, then SELECT DISTINCT would be the right answer.

Comment: I don't think that is correct mathguy, look at the sample data I added to the original request. I have duplicate customer records, that have the same email address. I only want to return one of them in the query.

Comment: @Bryan - we are disagreeing over the meaning of "duplicate". Rows with different cid are not duplicates of each other, even though they have the same email. But I understand what you are saying now; the email is "unique" but you have multiple cid's and uuid's for the same email, and you just want to pick one. Got that.